# How can I redirect a client with python 3?

Tags: python, http, redirect, client

I've got my handler setup but after the client requested something via the webbrowser I want the client to be redirected to the default webpage ("/").

I wrote my own http server handler.

How can I rederect a client using python 3 to another address?

Comment: How are you serving webpages with python3? Are you using a framework or you wrote an HTTP server on your own?

Comment: I wrote my own http server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a 302 redirect to the user's browser.
An example redirect header looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /
```

Refer to RFC2616, section 10.3 [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for all redirect status codes.